# Getting negative status based on filed ID

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, powerbi-desktop

I have two table as Table A and Table B. Both the table share the same ID. I want to add 3rd column in table A which will give me the price of table A either positive or negative based on the ID status of table B.  for example in table A price is 30 for the ID 1 but in table B ID 1 is negative so the value of 30 becomes negative -30. How can i achieve this. Any help on this much appriciated.

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Related function here, Which returns a related value from another table.

Create a calculated column like below:

```
MyNewColumn = IF(RELATED(TableB[Status]) = "Negative",TableA[Price]*-1,TableA[Price]*1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you bro, it really worked :) much appriciated.